# Using a MOSFET as a DCR

Tags: operational-amplifier, mosfet

I am trying to design a variable gain amplifier using a non inverting amplifier as a starting topology.

[image: Non Inverting amplifier]

The way I intend to do it is by replacing R2 with a circuit as the following one.

[image]

It works great when the mosfet is fully on/off, when the mosfet is fully off, the gain is given by

```
Vout/Vin =  1 + (R1 / (R2 + R3))
Vout/Vin =  1 + (R1 / (R2 + R3)) = 1 + (1.2k / (400 + 100k)) = 1 + (0.011) = 1.01
Vout/Vin = 1 (aprox)
```

On the other side, when the MOSFET is fully on, we can neglect Rds on and assume a direct connection to ground is done, hence disabling any current flow through R3 and with that we can simplify the transfer function to:

```
Vout/Vin = 1 + (R1 / R2)
Vout/Vin = 1 + (1.2k / 400) = (1 + 3) = 4
```

With this configuration, by using the mosfet in its ohmic region the gain of the amplifier it's fully dependant on the mosfet Vgs. When Vgs < Vgs_th the gain is at its minimum, in this case aproximately 1. On the other side, when Vgs >> Vgs_th, the mosfet is fully on and its gain its at its maximum, in this case 4.

The downside of this configuration is that this introduces distortion to to the output waveform when the mosfet is not fully on/off, below is a picture, where the top plot represents Vgs, the middle represents Vin, and the bottom one is Vout

[image]

Is there a better way to aproach this?
Is there a way to reduce this distortion?

Thanks for sharing your thoughts.

Comment: The audio circuits I’ve seen use a jfet.

Comment: An H11F1 opto-FET has a fairly linear resistance characteristic for small signals of 100 mV or so.